# How to customise a homebrew bottle's URL for a tap?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I am trying to write my first homebrew formula for some (Rust) piece of software and would like to be able to define bottle URL that points to already built software on GH.
Here is how the formula look like:

```
class Mithril < Formula
  desc "Cardano's Mithril client, signer, and aggregator executables"
  homepage "https://mithril.network"
  license "Apache License 2.0"
  version "2337.0"
  url "https://github.com/input-output-hk/mithril/releases/download/2337.0/mithril-2337.0-macos-x64.tar.gz"
  sha256 "f17f90f6021603570ca4a0cc403b6c13f5e6baae0196406ddadc565be7464595"

  depends_on "rust" => :build

  bottle do
    root_url "https://github.com/input-output-hk/mithril/releases/download/" 
    sha256 arm64_ventura: "f17f90f6021603570ca4a0cc403b6c13f5e6baae0196406ddadc565be7464595"
  end

..
end
```

The download URL is constructed from the `root_url` attribute, the version, and the architecture to yield `https://github.com/input-output-hk/mithril/releases/download/mithril-2337.0.arm64_ventura.tar.gz` which is incorrect. I would like the URL to b
`https://github.com/input-output-hk/mithril/releases/download/2337.0/mithril-2337.0.arm64_ventura.tar.gz`.

How do I interpolate the `version` attribute into the `root_url`?